# Cannot reproduce the first example from XML library in R

Tags: xml, r

When I run:

```
example(readHTMLTable)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: failed to load HTTP resource
```

Library XML is installed and running. This is my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
 R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reshape2_1.4  ggplot2_1.0.0 XML_3.98-1.1  dplyr_0.2    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1   colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     grid_3.1.1       gtable_0.1.2    
 [6] magrittr_1.0.1   MASS_7.3-33      munsell_0.4.2    parallel_3.1.1   plyr_1.8.1      
[11] proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.2      scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.1
```

Do I need to install additional libraries?

Comment: Can you also add the output from calling `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: I get this Error sometimes. I suggest restarting the R session, and if that doesn't help you may want to copy the examples into their own file.  Then add a line that uses `getURL`, from the `RCurl` package, to get the content.  Also, `gc()` and `free()` if you've been working with a lot of XML docs

Comment: Here's a related thread from R-help:  http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/htmlParse-from-XML-library-working-sporadically-in-the-same-code-td4661943.html.  The author of XML answers the question directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When that error happens, load the `httr` package and call it.  Here is an example from my own work where the first XML call returned the error but the httr call did not:

```
require(httr)

doc <- htmlTreeParse('http://www.lewisthomason.com/locations/', useInternal = TRUE)
doc <- content(GET('http://www.lewisthomason.com/locations/'))
```